# How can I print strings from array in bash?

Tags: bash

given the following array:

```
arr=("hello hello" "bye bye")
```

How can I print any element from `arr` to stdout?

I tried to do it by the next way:

```
for line in ${arr[*]}; do
    echo ${line}
done
```

But in this state, the output is:
hello
hello
bye
bye

And I want to get:
hello hello
bye bye

Comment: @anubhava, this is not a duplicate, OP need to PRINT elements, not looping over the array

Comment: OP has shown code that is attempting to loop through an array and print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just met [*shell word splitting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting).

---

If you quote (like you should), all is OK :

```
$ for line in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$line"; done
```

Can be just ([don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

### Output :

```
hello hello
bye bye
```

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

---

The difference between `$@` and `$*`: `"$@"` (quoted) expands to each positional parameter as its own argument: `"$1"` `"$2"` ... while `"$*"` expands to the single argument `"$1c$2c..."` where `c` is the first character of `IFS`. Unquoted `$*` and `$@` are `undefined`; **DO NOT use**. You almost always want `"$@"`. **The same goes for arrays**: `"${array[@]}"`

Comment: can you explain why with `${arr[@]}` it's not working? and what is the difference between `arr[@]` to `arr[*]` ?

Comment: Check my edited post (last paragraph)

Comment: amazing. thank you!!

Comment: hello, can you help me here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097914/reverse-of-any-line-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 0):

I think it should read:

```
arr=("hello hello" "bye bye")
for line in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    echo $line
done
```

bash is trying to do it's best to interpret.

Comment: can you explain why with `${arr[@]}` it's not working? and what is the difference between `arr[@]` to `arr[*]` ?